# Example of a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $\Gamma = \omega_1  \mathbb{Z} + \omega_2 \mathbb{Z}$ with $\omega_1, \omega_2$ independent over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $E_{\Gamma} = \mathbb{C}{/ \Gamma}$. Show that $E_{\Gamma}$ is a Riemann surface.

We have that $E_{\Gamma}$ is a topological manifold since it is homeomorphic to the torus. Furthermore, if we represent it on the complex plane, it coincides with the parallelogram generated by $\omega_1, \omega_2$. Now, as an open cover for $E_{\Gamma}$, we take a tessellation (for example, with open rectangles), and as charts, we consider those that map these open sets to themselves up to translation. Then, taking two open sets that intersect, the gluing function maps the intersection to itself up to translation, making it a holomorphic function. I would like to know if this is acceptable and if there is a more formal way to express this properly...

Comment: I think you mean that _1 and _2 are linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: @DanAsimov No, I think it means two vectors in $\Bbb C$ ($\cong\Bbb R^2$) are independent over $\Bbb R$, i.e. not collinear

Comment: The torus that is ℂ/ does not, of course "coincide with" the parallelogram **P** that is the fundamental domain of the group  acting on ℂ.  But it may be useful for your question to observe that *any* translated version z + **P** (where z is any complex number) works equally well as a fundamental domain for .

Answer (score 0):

More generally, see [5. Riemann surfaces as quotients](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/%7Ews442/complex.pdf)

> Theorem 4.13. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ and $G \subset
> \operatorname{Aut}\left(\mathbb{C}_{\infty}\right)$ with the property
> that
>
> - $g(\Omega) \subset \Omega$ for all $g \in G$
> - for all $g \in G, g \neq \mathrm{id}$, all fixed points of $g$ in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ lie outside of $\Omega$
> - let $K \subset \Omega$ be compact. Then the cardinality of $\{g \in G \mid g(K) \cap K \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite.
>
> Under these assumptions, the natural projection $\pi: \Omega
>  \rightarrow \Omega / G$ is a covering map which turns $\Omega / G$
> canonically into a Riemann surface.

$\Bbb C/Γ$ in your question is in the list of examples after this theorem.